# populating text boxes from selected item in combo box

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, list, combobox

I have added a new interface to an existing utility that will read data stored on an external device. This requires taking XML response and deserializing them to a list. Here is the xml and the code for list creation (to copy all element, attribute, type declarations would be too lengthy here.):

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Device>
<Response>
    <command>Get</command>
    <argument>AllMethod</argument>
</Response>
<AllMethod>
<Method>
    <nMethodNumber>1</nMethodNumber>
    <sMethodName>Method-8</sMethodName>
    <fFlowRate>3.00</fFlowRate>
    <nTubeTemp>250</nTubeTemp>
    <nTestTime>150</nTestTime>
</Method>
<Method>
    <nMethodNumber>2</nMethodNumber>
    <sMethodName>Method-8</sMethodName>
    <fFlowRate>3.00</fFlowRate>
    <nTubeTemp>250</nTubeTemp>
    <nTestTime>150</nTestTime>
</Method>
<Method>
    <nMethodNumber>3</nMethodNumber>
    <sMethodName>Method-8</sMethodName>
    <fFlowRate>3.00</fFlowRate>
    <nTubeTemp>250</nTubeTemp>
    <nTestTime>150</nTestTime>
</Method>
<Method>
    <nMethodNumber>4</nMethodNumber>
    <sMethodName>Method-8</sMethodName>
    <fFlowRate>3.00</fFlowRate>
    <nTubeTemp>250</nTubeTemp>
    <nTestTime>150</nTestTime>
</Method>
<Method>
    <nMethodNumber>5</nMethodNumber>
    <sMethodName>Method-8</sMethodName>
    <fFlowRate>3.00</fFlowRate>
    <nTubeTemp>250</nTubeTemp>
    <nTestTime>150</nTestTime>
</Method>
<Method>
    <nMethodNumber>6</nMethodNumber>
    <sMethodName>Method-8</sMethodName>
    <fFlowRate>3.00</fFlowRate>
    <nTubeTemp>250</nTubeTemp>
    <nTestTime>150</nTestTime>
</Method>
<Method>
    <nMethodNumber>7</nMethodNumber>
    <sMethodName>Method-8</sMethodName>
    <fFlowRate>3.00</fFlowRate>
    <nTubeTemp>250</nTubeTemp>
    <nTestTime>150</nTestTime>
</Method>
<Method>
    <nMethodNumber>8</nMethodNumber>
    <sMethodName>Method-8</sMethodName>
    <fFlowRate>3.00</fFlowRate>
    <nTubeTemp>250</nTubeTemp>
    <nTestTime>150</nTestTime>
</Method>   
</AllMethod>
</Device>
```

Create List:

```
public class AllMethod
{
[XmlElement("Method")]
//Puts Methods into list for deserialization.
public List<Method> methodlist = new List<Method>();
}
```

I have created the XML document locally to test the functionality of the program before going live. So in my Read Methods button event I have the following code:

```
private void btnReadMethod_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        string stringRequestXML = string.Empty;
        string stringResponseXML = string.Empty;

{
        //Will deserialize xml response and populate combo box with method numbers.
        //try
        //{
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new   XmlSerializer(typeof(ReadMethodResponse));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\XML\GetAllXml.xml");
        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        ReadMethodResponse XmlData = (ReadMethodResponse)obj;
        reader.Close();


        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        // throw ex;
        //}

        cmbMethodNumber.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Method details in XmlData.allMethods.methodlist)
        {
        cmbMethodNumber.Items.Add(details.MethodNumber);
        }



        }

        }

    private void cmbMethodNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int MethodDetailsIndex = cmbMethodNumber.SelectedIndex;
        Method selectedMethod = xmlData.allMethods.methodlist[MethodDetailsIndex];
        txtMethodName.Text = selectedMethod.MethodName.ToString();
        txtFlow.Text = selectedMethod.FlowRate.ToString();
        txtTubeTemp.Text = selectedMethod.TubeTemp.ToString();
        txtTestTime.Text = selectedMethod.TestTime.ToString();
    }


}
```

I have a combobox to display method number and three textboxes to display method name, flow rate, test time, and temp. I am trying to populate the text boxes with the correct information based on the selected value (Method Number) of the combobox. My code for deserializing the xml is functioning fine but I am having trouble populating the text boxes with the corresponding data. I cannot access the list from the cmbMethodNumber_SelectedIndexChanged.
This is probably fairly simple but I am fairly new to c# and google is not my friend today, any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot access the list"?  Is there an error message?  Where/how is the list declared?

Comment: In the bottom block of code: Intellisense states: "xmlData" does not exist in the current context. (I know its a different method) but that is where I get fuzzy on working with the list. The only place I have it declared is under the XmlElement "Method" as public List<Method> methodlist = new List<Method>();

Comment: I'm only seeing bits and pieces of the overall structure, so I can't know the scope of your variables.  You definitely need the data to be class-level in order for multiple event handlers to access it.  Maybe the `xmlData` object should be declared as a class-level member instead of within the method scope?  It's not clear if that's what you're trying to access, since you're also talking about some other list.

Comment: Sorry David. I really do not know if what I am trying to do is valid as this is the first time I have worked with these response packets. I just want to take all the methods in the xml and store in a list. I want to use that list to populate my combobox with method numbers and then based on the users selection automatically populate the text boxes with the corresponding method data such as flow rate, test time, tube temp, etc.

Comment: I really do not know how to do it so this was my initial stab at it. Most of the info I find on the net pertains to users entering data into a list then serializing (not helpful). I know that my list is there as I can verify then info in debug. I can even populate the combo box with the method numbers. its binding the additional data to the text boxes based on that selected item that I cant get right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a lot of meaningful information to go on, but it *seems* like the problem is just variable scoping.  Essentially, you're doing this:

```
private void btnReadMethod_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var xmlData = SomeFunctionToGetData();
}

private void cmbMethodNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var someValue = xmlData.SomeValue;
}
```

Naturally, `xmlData` doesn't exist in the second function, so it can't be referenced.  It was declared in the scope of the first function, and once that function ended it was removed from scope.  This doesn't have anything to do with your XML or the overall business problem you're trying to solve, it's just a variable scope error.

In order for multiple handlers to access this data (that is, in order for the scope of the data to last across multiple events on the form), it needs to be a class-level object.  Something more like this:

```
private TheTypeOfTheObject xmlData;

private void btnReadMethod_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    xmlData = SomeFunctionToGetData();
}

private void cmbMethodNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var someValue = xmlData.SomeValue;
}
```

I've added the variable to class-level scope, and removed the declaration in the first function.  Now the first function sets the class-level value, and the second function reads the class-level value.  Of course, this makes a few assumptions:

- The second function will never run unless the first function has successfully run before it.
- Other handlers aren't also modifying the value.

You probably want to add some error checking and exception handling if there are scenarios where these assumptions aren't true.